# how to separate driver settings on two physics caches

Tags: drivers, cache

I need to cease a physics simulation for a series of frames, and possibly re-bake the simulation when I adjust the animation by scaling areas that will include certain timeline markers.  As an example there are times when a soft-body (lattice modifier) keeps moving a hair-mesh when the character is still, even after too many property adjustments -- its just easier to have no soft-body movement during these frames.   I don't want to do this manually as I have too many of these sims within several scenes; some with 1000+ frames and several breaks between simulations.  This will also allow for scripted re-bakes from command line, pre-render.

To achieve this I create two caches with appropriate stop and stop times:

[image]
[image]

All's fine thus far.  Now I want to drive the start/end frames from timeline marker names and problems begin.  If I add drivers to start/end of both caches end edit in Drivers Editor, I can see that the cache names are distinguished in the editor, but changes to the first or second caches driver variables

[image]

are then forced upon the other caches values:

[image]

am I missing some technique?  Is this possibly a bug?

Example file: [image]

Comment: may i ask why you need to have stop times? after baking it, you can stop at any frame and move the keyframes and e.g. animate then the camera to get a Matrix like effect. Or did i misunderstood what you wanna do?

Comment: @Chris -- thanks for your attention.  I edited the first paragraph to provide more motivation/goal.

Comment: @Chris -- I also end my question: "Is this possibly a bug?"